# What's the intention of opencpu.org compared to other approaches?

Tags: r, rpy2, opencpu, rapache

Lately I was pointed to http://opencpu.org/ . Nifty website, but after browsing for a little while I wasn't so sure where it is located in the R landscape compared to e.g. [rApache](http://rapache.net/) or [RPy2](http://rpy2.bitbucket.org/).

After waiting a long time for the server to come back I was finally able to read the architecture section, but that wasn't too comprehensive. **I'm looking for a more detailed explanation of what OpenCPU is, how it is intended to be used, and how this compares with existing tools such as [rApache](http://rapache.net/) and [RPy2](http://rpy2.bitbucket.org/).**

Comment: Interesting, but I'm not sure what the question is here, so I've had to vote to close

Comment: Can your question be rephrased as: "How does opencpu.org compare to rApache or Rstudio server?"  If so, then please do so.  As-is it is a little hard to answer definitively.  Waggishly, I'd say it fits into the Westwood area of the R landscape.

Comment: I made an attempt to focus the question a bit towards something less likely to attract close votes. I hope I still captured the spirit of what you're asking.

Comment: I like joran's edit and I hope I´d rather will extract answers then close votes. @Iterator: I did not want to name specific technology in the header because I did not want to limit it. Your comment shows that I was right about that, since I did not even think about RStudio Server. Good point though. Maybe, "What's the intention of opencpu.org as opposed to other comparable technologies..?" would do better – i'll try that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In a nutshell: OpenCPU is a layer on top of the regular tools (e.g. RApache, rpy2) that defines a framework and protocol for interacting with R. It handles stuff like object serialization, security, resource control, reproducibility etc, while abstracting away technicalities.

This [paper on arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/1406.4806) goes into more detail on the motivation and design of the system and API.